# Windows Desktop USB Port as a Device ( and not as a Host )

Tags: windows, usb, kernel, driver, hid

### Use-case description ( USB Remoting )

---

- 2 Windows Desktop machines are connected using a USB cable
- Desktop machine **[A]** simulate a HID keyboard for the USB connected Desktop machine **[B]**

### Implementation

---

For desktop machine **[A]** ( that simulate the HID Keyboard ), the USB Should act as a USB Device ( and not as a USB Host ), and hence, register on Desktop machine **[B]** PNP Manager as a HID Keyboard, while on the same time, It **shouldn't register** on the PNP manager of machine **[A]** ( the machine simulating the HID Keyboard ).

### Questions

---

- Does windows support setting up a USB Port/Bus as a Device and not as a Host ( assuming OTG support ) ?
- If not, is there any off-the-shelf HW/SW supporting this kind of functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of USB interfaces:

1) USB Host
2) USB Device
3) USB OTG (On The Go - Host + Device)

USB Host port cannot be configured to work as USB device port and typically desktop motherboard come only with USB Host port.

Comment: Are you familiar with any Desktop MotherBoard or peripheral that supports USB OTG such that it can directly be used from the Desktop machine in the above mentioned manner ?

Comment: You cannot connect two PC motherboards using a USB cable and Motherboards come with USB host port only. Can you tell me exactly what you are trying to do. Why do you want to use Desktop A to emulate as a HID device?

Comment: I want eg. a desktop to simulate a SmartPhone keyboard accessory , for that, it seems I need OTG @ desktop...

Comment: Yes you are correct. If you want to emulate a KB which is a USB device, you need a MB with USB OTG or Device which unfortunately are not available.

Comment: If my answer helped you please flag it as correct answer.